# Procedural Character Generation (Blender & Unity)

Tags: unity

I started 3D modelling a few weeks ago, and I'm having a blast! I have a 3d Model with shape keys setup and I'm working on creating hair objects (I have 5 right now). After I create some more hairstyles, I'm going to want to rig the model up, create animations and create various pants, shoes, shirts, hats, etc.

Do I have to create bones that attach to each of the swappables I'm adding? Is there any way to put all of the hairstyles into a group and attach that to the base character? Better yet - a way to create shape keys that apply to everything in the 'hair' group? I would do the same with the shirts, pants, etc - but I'm looking for best Blender to Unity practices.

My goal is for everything to be attached to the character and move with it when I start animating. After it looks good, to import it to Unity and create scripts to dynamically create characters on the click of a button. Are there tutorials that you recommend for something like this?

Comment: Not really my area, but as far as I know shapekeys work on a per-single-object basis, not on groups of objects. Maybe you might want to look into Lattices and the Lattice modifier instead for deforming several objects at once, or full rigging

Comment: While it might be a bit complex for most beginners, the CGCookie [flexrig](https://cgcookie.com/resource/cg-cookie-flex-rig/) might give you some ideas. The drivers it uses won't export to unity but you should be able to apply or bake the variations before exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Blend Shapes -- it got me what I needed.